# Writing my own shell in C, how do I run Unix executables?

Tags: c, shell, unix, path

In one of my courses we're writing our own shell (basically from scratch).

We've already handled writing a lexer and a parser to divide the input into nice "command" structures that are easier to deal with.  Likewise, I have a function `read_command()` that will read one command in at a time and figure out what type of command it is (pipe/and/or/simple/etc.).

I now am trying to write the `execute_command(struct command cmd)` function that actually takes the command and runs it.  I'm struggling on how to even start actually writing this function.

Let's say I just get a very simple `cat foo.txt` as the command.  My command structure will divide it up neatly so I have a word array with both words in it.

Now I want to run the `cat` executable with the argument `foo.txt`.  I realize I should use the `$PATH` variable to try to find the executable and then run it with this argument.

I'm struggling with a few major questions:

1. How do I actually search for the command `cat`?  Keep in mind this program uses C.  What functions can I use to search through directories?  How do I use PATH to do this?
2. When I do find the command `cat`, how can I run it with `foo.txt` as a parameter?  How can this be done in C?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Check out [`getenv(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) and its relatives.  You probably don't actually need to directly do any operations on directories, but if you do, you can use [`opendir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), [`closedir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir), etc.
2. Use [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [`execl(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) or one of its relatives ([`execve(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) is the base-level API).

The man pages themselves or a simple google search for any of these functions will turn up plenty of examples to help you along.

Comment: You don't need to process `PATH` yourself. `execvp` will do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

You split the command string up into separate strings (command name, arguments), and you store them in a null terminated array of character pointers.  You then fork and pass the command name and the command + arguments to `execvp()`, unless that's verboten.  You will eventually have to worry about pipes and I/O redirection too, but the basic idea remains the same.

```
char *args[MAXARGS];

args[0] = "cat";
args[1] = "foo.txt";
args[2] = 0;

if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
    execvp(args[0], args);
    ...print error...
    exit(1);
    /* execvp() does not return unless there's an error */
}
else if (pid < 0)
    ...fork failed...
else
    ...wait for child to finish - or start other commands, or ...
```

You might dynamically allocate `args` in a real shell.  It gets one step trickier if you have to supply a custom environment to the executed program.  Basically, you'll assemble a copy of the environment, and then after forking, set the global `environ` to the new value - but if the new environment contains a new value for PATH, that will affect the search for the command by `execvp()`.  So you may end up writing your own variant of `execvp()` because of that.  If so, take a leaf out of the BSD (MacOS X) book; there is a function `execvP()`:

```
 int execvP(const char *file, const char *search_path, char *const argv[]);
```

which allows you to specify the search path to use, even though you've fixed the environment.  The most fundamental call is `execve()`; this is used by `execvp()` behind the scenes (possibly via `execv()`).